# Apache Hudi on Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-hudi

Is there any guide to deploy Apache Hudi on a Dataproc Cluster? i´m trying to deploy via
[Hudi Quick Start Guide](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/quick-start-guide/) but i can´t.

Spark 3.1.1

Python 3.8.13

Debian 5.10.127 x86_64

launch code:

```
pyspark --jars gs://bucket/artifacts/hudi-spark3.1.x_2.12-0.11.1.jar,gs://bucket/artifacts/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.3.jar \
--conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' \
--conf 'spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog'
```

Try:

```
dataGen = sc._jvm.org.apache.hudi.QuickstartUtils.DataGenerator()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Edit 1:

```
pyspark --jars gs://bucket/artifacts/hudi-spark3.1.x_2.12-0.11.1.jar,gs://bucket/artifacts/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.3.jar --conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' --conf 'spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension'
```

Throw conf error

WARN org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession: Cannot use org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension to configure session extensions. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension.

and also get same error trying sc._jvm.org.apache.hudi.QuickstartUtils.DataGenerator()

Edit 2:

I was using wrong .jar..., this edit correct first problem

Correct pyspark call:

```
pyspark --jars gs://dev-dama-stg-spark/artifacts/hudi-spark3.1-bundle_2.12-0.12.1.jar,gs://dev-dama-stg-spark/artifacts/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.3.jar --conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' --conf 'spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension'
```

However, new errors... after create table and hudi.options:

```
22/12/01 22:26:04 WARN org.apache.hudi.common.config.DFSPropertiesConfiguration: Cannot find HUDI_CONF_DIR, please set it as the dir of hudi-defaults.conf
22/12/01 22:26:04 WARN org.apache.hudi.common.config.DFSPropertiesConfiguration: Properties file file:/etc/hudi/conf/hudi-defaults.conf not found. Ignoring to load props file
22/12/01 22:26:05 WARN org.apache.hudi.metadata.HoodieBackedTableMetadata: Metadata table was not found at path file:/tmp/hudi_trips_cow/.hoodie/metadata
22/12/01 22:26:07 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) (... 2): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hudi_trips_cow does not exist
```

Any clues...?

Comment: Seems you are not following the Hudi 0.11.1 guide for Spark 3.1 strictly. The guide has `spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension`, and does not have `spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog` https://hudi.apache.org/docs/0.11.1/quick-start-guide

Comment: Hî there, if i put this --conf i recive: 22/12/01 21:42:24 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession: Cannot use org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension to configure session extensions.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension. Edit1: and also get same error trying sc._jvm.org.apache.hudi.QuickstartUtils.DataGenerator()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution my self.

first, to launch correctly pyspark, include **hudi-spark_bundle** and **spark-avro** as jars. Also, in my case i want to include some jdbc jars to connect with my on-premise service:`

```
pyspark --jars gs://bucket/artifacts/hudi-spark3.1-bundle_2.12-0.12.1.jar,
gs://bucket/artifacts/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.3.jar,
gs://bucket/artifacts/mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre8.jar,
gs://bucket/artifacts/ngdbc-2.12.9.jar \
--conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' \
--conf 'spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension'
```

Follow the hudi quick guide and the only thing to change from this:

```
basePath = "file:///tmp/hudi_trips_cow"
```

to this

```
basePath = "gs://bucket/tmp/hudi_trips_cow"
```

With this configuration i was able to run correctly hudi in Dataproc.

If i find new information i will- post here to keep this as a short guide.